# Torus action on hypersurface of multidegree $(1,1,1,1)$ in $(\mathbb{CP}^{1})^{4}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-actions

Let $X$ be a (smooth) hypersurface of mulidegree $(1,1,1,1)$ in $(\mathbb{CP}^{1})^{4}$. According to table $6$ (page 19) in the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.01089.pdf, we have:

1. $X$ has a non-trivial $\mathbb{C}^{*}$-action that is semi-free (i.e. stabiliser of every point is either $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ or the trivial subgroup).
2. $h^{1,2} = 1$.

**Question:** How to describe a $\mathbb{C}^{*}$-action as in 1.?

(Note: I don't think that this action can be induced from a linear action on $(\mathbb{CP}^{1})^{4}$, since any $\mathbb{C}^{*}
$ necessarily fixes a smooth curve of genus $1$ on $X$ (by fact 2)).

Comment: I doubt that such a $\mathbb{C}^\times$-action exists. 

Indeed, the pullbacks $L_1$, $L_2$, $L_3$, $L_4$ of the line bundles $\mathcal{O}(1)$ from the factors of $(\mathbb{P}^1)^4$ generate the ample cone of $X$, so any automorphism should permute them. Since $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is connected, it actually fixes each $L_i$. Therefore, any $\mathbb{C}^\times$-action on $X$ is induced by an action on $(\mathbb{P}^1)^4$.